# How do I detect a WM_KEYDOWN on child window?

Tags: winapi, keyboard, focus, onkeydown

For a standard control like button, edit, etc I can subclass it but how is this done for a child window(I'm using as a container)? I know the `WM_KEYDOWN` is sent to the parent window but I couldn't get it directly from the respective child window. I've tried subclassing it(not sure if this does make sense since it's a window and has its own window procedure already in the `WNDCLASSW.lpfnWndProc` member) but this subprocedure didn't get a `WM_KEYDOWN` message anyway. I can get the control's hwnd from the cursor position (I need to consider keyboard focus too) by using `GetCursorPos()` and `WindowFromPoint()` like below but I feel it's hacky. What's the proper way to do this?

currently it look like this:

```
    case WM_KEYUP:
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        POINT p;
        if(GetCursorPos(&p))
        {
            HWND control = WindowFromPoint(p);
            if(control)
            {
                // just testing it
                int len = GetWindowTextLength(control);
                wchar_t buffer[len + 1];
                GetWindowText(control, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"", MB_OK);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

the window look like this:

[image]

the goal is catch the WM_KEYDOWN on the respective window where the user typed something, then call a function to deal with this event, like `window1_onKeyDown()`, `window2_onKeyDown()` and such.

Here's full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc1(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void createWindow1(HWND);
void createWindow2(HWND);

HBRUSH hBrush1, hBrush2;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG  msg;    
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"my window";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    hBrush1 = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(173, 164, 237));
    hBrush2 = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(171, 171, 171));

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"window",
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  100, 100, 330, 270, NULL, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    DeleteObject(hBrush1);
    DeleteObject(hBrush2);

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg)
    {

        case WM_CREATE:
            createWindow1(hwnd);
            createWindow2(hwnd);
        break;

      
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            POINT p;
            if(GetCursorPos(&p))
            {
                HWND control = WindowFromPoint(p);
                if(control)
                {
                    int len = GetWindowTextLength(control);
                    wchar_t buffer[len + 1];
                    GetWindowText(control, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"", MB_OK);
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void createWindow1(HWND hOwner)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"window2";
    wc.hInstance     = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = hBrush1;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc1;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"window2",
                  WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT,
                  5, 5, 200, 100, 
                  hOwner, 0, NULL, 0);
}

void createWindow2(HWND hOwner)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"window3";
    wc.hInstance     = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = hBrush2;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc2;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"window3",
                  WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD,
                  5, 120, 200, 100, 
                  hOwner, 0, NULL, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc1(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Button A", 
                         WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD,
                         5, 5, 80, 25,
                         hwnd, 0, NULL, 0);
        break;

        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"hello from proc1", L"", MB_OK);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Button ", 
                         WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD,
                         5, 5, 80, 25,
                         hwnd, 0, NULL, 0);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: [Those who do not understand the dialog manager are doomed to reimplement it, badly](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070627-00/?p=26243).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SetFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus) in the child window.

Some code:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        POINT p;
        HWND control = GetFocus();
        if (control)
        {
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(control);
            wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[len + 1];
            GetWindowText(control, buffer, len + 1);
            MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"", MB_OK);
        }
    }
    break;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc1(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Button A",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD,
            5, 5, 80, 25,
            hwnd, 0, NULL, 0);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        SetFocus(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        MessageBox(NULL, L"hello from proc1", L"", MB_OK);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

You can also use the current method, and then use PostMessage/SendMessage to forward the `WM_KEYDOWN` message to the child window:

```
    if (control)
    {
        int len = GetWindowTextLength(control);
        wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[len + 1];
        GetWindowText(control, buffer, len + 1);
        MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"", MB_OK);
        PostMessage(hwnd_child, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903).